Sorting issue when consolidating monthly data into a year to date file. Using query, sorting by day, time, and letter
I am collecting data from each month on measured parts into a single file for the whole year. When using a "query from folder" I am able to get all the data together, formatted, and sorted with one exception. Every part has an "A" and a "B" version. Unfortunately, due to production order, sometimes the "B" part is measured before the "A" part. In this case I would not want to sort by time as the order would then go, for example, A,B,A,B,B,A,A,B,A,B. I want it to always place the "A" part before the "B" part. Parts are measured twice per day so I cannot sort by day and then part letter because it would then go, for example, A,A,B,B,A,A,B,B. How can I sort the data such that it goes by day, then time, then overwrites time to keep the A,B,A,B pattern?
To further complicate things, sometimes the data collector messes up and mislabels one of the parts. In this case it would sort as, for example, A,B,A,B,A,A,A,B,A,B. How can I find this error and correct it automatically before pasting the consolidated data into a table.
(Data has been over simplified for confidentiality reasons)
You can see on May 2nd in the morning A/B are reversed because B data was taken before A data. Sorting the data by time messed up the order.
You can see on April 2nd in the morning (1PM is morning shift) there are two A parts when one of them should be B (for this error we can assume they were taken in the order of "A" before "B" so the time of data collection applies).
I am new to using queries and honestly struggling hard on this one. Please help me not only solve this problem but also understand it.
Here are text versions of the data:
Apr



Date
Time
Letter
Data




4/1/2024
7:25:08 AM
A
0.7


4/1/2024
7:30:56 AM
B
0.5


4/1/2024
8:32:51 PM
A
0.6


4/1/2024
8:36:44 PM
B
0.5


4/2/2024
1:32:59 PM
A
1


4/2/2024
1:38:36 PM
A
0.5


4/2/2024
8:46:11 PM
A
0.7


4/2/2024
8:51:31 PM
B
0.7



May



Date
Time
Letter
Data




5/1/2024
1:35:12 PM
A
0.6


5/1/2024
1:39:05 PM
B
0.4


5/1/2024
6:07:11 PM
A
0.8


5/1/2024
6:10:43 PM
B
0.5


5/2/2024
10:59:32 AM
A
0.8


5/2/2024
8:42:16 AM
B
0.1


5/2/2024
6:15:07 PM
A
0.4


5/2/2024
6:18:40 PM
B
0.2



YTD (Current output)



Date
Time
Letter
Data










4/1/2024
7:25:08 AM
A
0.7


4/1/2024
7:30:56 AM
B
0.5


4/1/2024
8:32:51 PM
A
0.6


4/1/2024
8:36:44 PM
B
0.5


4/2/2024
1:32:59 PM
A
1


4/2/2024
1:38:36 PM
A
0.5


4/2/2024
8:46:11 PM
A
0.7


4/2/2024
8:51:31 PM
B
0.7


5/1/2024
1:35:12 PM
A
0.6


5/1/2024
1:39:05 PM
B
0.4


5/1/2024
6:07:11 PM
A
0.8


5/1/2024
6:10:43 PM
B
0.5


5/2/2024
8:42:16 AM
B
0.1


5/2/2024
10:59:32 AM
A
0.8


5/2/2024
6:15:07 PM
A
0.4


5/2/2024
6:18:40 PM
B
0.2



YTD (Desired output)



Date
Time
Letter
Data










4/1/2024
7:25:08 AM
A
0.7


4/1/2024
7:30:56 AM
B
0.5


4/1/2024
8:32:51 PM
A
0.6


4/1/2024
8:36:44 PM
B
0.5


4/2/2024
1:32:59 PM
A
1


4/2/2024
1:38:36 PM
B
0.5


4/2/2024
8:46:11 PM
A
0.7


4/2/2024
8:51:31 PM
B
0.7


5/1/2024
1:35:12 PM
A
0.6


5/1/2024
1:39:05 PM
B
0.4


5/1/2024
6:07:11 PM
A
0.8


5/1/2024
6:10:43 PM
B
0.5


5/2/2024
10:59:32 AM
A
0.8


5/2/2024
8:42:16 AM
B
0.1


5/2/2024
6:15:07 PM
A
0.4


5/2/2024
6:18:40 PM
B
0.2



I used a simple power query as seen here and additionally, in order, changed all the data types to the correct type, sorted by date, sorted by time, removed source name, and removed duplicates.
The reason I cannot rely on file names to sort the data and keep it as it is within the file is because I am pulling data from sheets that all have the same name but are in their own respective monthly folders. Folders sort alphabetically so the order of the months would be wrong if I didn't manually sort it.

Post your data as text, nobody wants to open a zip file!

@Toto I am unsure of how to copy the excel data as text. When I copy it only pastes as an image

Look at the help, it is posible to format text as table.

@Toto yeah that is way too much to manually format as a table. I think the way Andrew did it is a nice middle ground

I'm wondering if there is a way to import the data twice, sort it, convert A on one set and B on the other set to 0. Divide 1 by the 0's to throw an error. Delete error rows, then recombine the two sets alternating every line? Can you combine data sets by alternating each line? Could this be done somehow without creating multiple sheets/tables?

@Toto I've updated the description to try to make my issue clearer

Markdown Table generator paste your data over there, take out the table it generates. Sample data is also possible, you don't need to give us every cell of your excel file.

@Excellor wow thats really convenient! Thanks!

@LightOfTheNight I think your problem may be fundamentally unsolvable without further context. The issue is that from the available data it's impossible to tell whether two parts which appear in the wrong order (i.e. B, A when sorted by time) are in fact in the wrong order or are actually both mislabeled.

@FlexYourData Yes but this is an issue of the process, not the code. Then that happens I want to just assume they're right. I just need a way to force the order to alternate A and B. I just brought up the mislabel issue because you cant alternate A and B if they're both A. So in that case just assume they're in the A then B order

Based on these assumptions as mentioned in your comment:

If there are two measurements of a part on the same day, they are assumed to be in the correct order and named incorrectly
If there are two measurements in B, A order on the same day, they are assumed to be in the incorrect order but named correctly

You can solve in this way:
Starting from the appended dataset:

Add an Index column:

Add a custom column which assigns a PaidID to each successive pair of rows:

Group By on PairID with a single column called 'Rows' set to 'All Rows':

Then edit the Table.Group definition as shown in the query:
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    ReType = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Date", type date}, {"Time", type time}, {"Letter", type text}, {"Data", type number}}),
    AddIndex = Table.AddIndexColumn(ReType, "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
    AddPairID = Table.AddColumn(AddIndex, "PairID", each Number.RoundDown([Index]/2)),
    GroupRows = Table.Group(
        AddPairID, 
        {"PairID"}, 
        {
            {
                "Rows", 
                each 
                    let 
                        // This switches rows that are in the wrong order and keeps other rows in the same order
                        sorted = Table.Sort(_, {{"Letter", Order.Ascending}, {"Index", Order.Ascending}}),
                        // At this point A should be at pos 0 and B at pos 1 - if they're not, they are re-lettered
                        newLetter = Table.AddColumn(
                            sorted, 
                            "NewLetter", 
                            each if [Letter]="A" and Table.PositionOf(sorted,_)=1 then "B" else 
                                 if [Letter]="B" and Table.PositionOf(sorted,_)=0 then "A" else [Letter])
                    in newLetter
                    
            }
        }, 
        GroupKind.Local
    ),
    ExpandedRows = Table.ExpandTableColumn(GroupRows, "Rows", {"Date", "Time", "NewLetter", "Data"}, {"Date", "Time", "Letter", "Data"}),
    RemovePairID = Table.RemoveColumns(ExpandedRows,{"PairID"})
in
    RemovePairID

Expand the table column (click the double-arrow at the top of the column) and ensure that the formula bar is as shown:

Finally remove the PairID column:


This works for the most part but I am running into some issues and have some questions.
First, I cannot do Int64.Type because it throws an error saying one of the functions expects 2 to 4 arguments but I provided 5. No clue why Table.AddIndexColumn isn't allowing a data type. Next. It says Index and PairID already exist in the record when I try to use them in the Table.Group code. If I switch them to Index1 and PairID1 it works but I do not understand why.

Last, can I delete the create column for Index and PairID since we do that anyway in the Table.Group code? I also couldn't expand the table column or remove PairID because Table.Group already does that.

To simplify things, get your data into the state where the queries are appended on top of each other and save that as a query. Say "AppendedData" or something. Then take all of the code from my answer, change the first step to say Source = AppendedData,

(set up my code as a new query that references your appended data)

I seem to have got it working. I didn't quite understand how each function calls the previous function output as the name given in that function (idk if im saying this right but I mean the name on the right bar). I still don't understand why I cannot change the index datatype though. Is there a restriction in older versions of excel or something? Im using Excel 2016

Not sure about any restrictions. I used the UI to create the index step and it auto-populates the data type. If you write the step by hand, you can omit it, I think.

Weird. When I used the UI to make an index column it only uses 4 arguments. Anyway it works so thank you!
I am also finding I need to ReType all the columns again after the group/edit/expand stuff for some reason

I posted what worked for me. Can you see why I needed the ReType2 line?

Flex has the answer but my Excel was not liking it so here is the modified version that worked for me
= let
Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Examples"]}[Content],
ReType = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Table Column1",{{"Source.Name", type text}, {"Date", type date}, {"Time", type time}, {"Letter", type text}, {"Data", type number}}),
SortTime = Table.Sort(ReType,{{"Date", Order.Ascending}, {"Time", Order.Ascending}}),
RemoveSource = Table.RemoveColumns(SortTime,{"Source.Name"}),
RemoveBlanks = Table.SelectRows(RemoveSource, each not List.IsEmpty(List.RemoveMatchingItems(Record.FieldValues(_), {"", null}))),
AddIndex = Table.AddIndexColumn(RemoveBlanks, "Index", 0, 1),
AddPairID = Table.AddColumn(AddIndex, "PairID", each Number.RoundDown([Index]/2)),
GroupRows = Table.Group(
    AddPairID, 
    {"PairID"}, 
    {
        {
            "Rows", 
            each 
                let 
                    // This switches rows that are in the wrong order and keeps other rows in the same order
                    sorted = Table.Sort(_, {{"Letter", Order.Ascending}, {"Index", Order.Ascending}}),
                    // At this point A should be at pos 0 and B at pos 1 - if they're not, they are re-lettered
                    newLetter = Table.AddColumn(
                        sorted, 
                        "NewLetter", 
                        each if [Letter]="A" and Table.PositionOf(sorted,_)=1 then "B" else 
                             if [Letter]="B" and Table.PositionOf(sorted,_)=0 then "A" else [Letter])
                in newLetter
                
        }
    }, 
    GroupKind.Local
),
ExpandedRows = Table.ExpandTableColumn(GroupRows, "Rows", {"Date", "Time", "NewLetter", "Data"}, {"Date", "Time", "Letter", "Data"}),
ReType2 = Table.TransformColumnTypes(ExpandedRows,{{"Date", type date}, {"Time", type time}, {"Letter", type text}, {"Data", type number}}),
RemovePairID = Table.RemoveColumns(ReType2,{"PairID"})
in
RemovePairID


It's not clear why you would need that step at all since the only step after it is removing a column. Are you saying that after expanding the column the data types aren't correct or as you would expect?

@FlexYourData If I remove ReType2 all the data is 123ABC type. Somewhere between grouping rows and expanding columns the data types are lost. its no biggie though because it still works just thought it was weird

Don't worry too much about the type it says on the UI. It doesn't change the values themselves. For a great understanding of types and Power Query in general: https://bengribaudo.com/blog/2017/11/17/4107/power-query-m-primer-part1-introduction-simple-expressions-let

@FlexYourData Thank you. I do have another request if you are up for it because I know I can't do it. Could you have it check that the two times in each group are within the shame shift? Then if they aren't delete the first row of data in the group and start over from the indexing?
I ask because when I ran the code on the full dataset I ran into an issue where everything got offset by 1 place. It happened because, for some reason I'll never know, someone took only B data one shift and not A. So that offset everything.

Imagine taking the test datasets and deleting April 1st 8:32:51PM row. When you run it you will see how it offsets everything
